# Magento 2 multiple store facing 404

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am creating a second store in the same website, for that i followed blow link
https://magefan.com/blog/create-multiple-stores-in-magento-2.

After Created a new store it's looking as below.
[image]

Then in that store I changed the base url and base secure url as like below
[image]

Now in my home page I've got the menu in footer section to view the second store.
[image]

But while view the second store i got the page as like below.
I've ran all the magento commands also, is there need to do any other configuration or something else, your better idea will help me more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is related to your second store base url configuration

You have 4 options to manage few stores under the same website:

1. **Cookie based logic (default)**. You need to have the same domain and path for all website stores. The system routes to store by cookie or request parameter.
2. **Store Code in URL**. You can enable to add store code in URL in Stores -> Configuration. In this case you also need to have same domain and path, but your code will be included in URL and the system routes to store by request URL path.
3. **Custom domain (subdomain) configuration**. You need to properly configure subdomain and pass `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` and `MAGE_RUN_CODE` environment variables with server configuration. In this case the system routes to store by environment variable.
4. **Custom directory or server URL Rewrite**. You can create custom directory under your `pub` directory and place custom `index.php` and specify required store with environment variables (the same like in 3rd option) or create rewrite rule on server level and route to `index.php` with needed  environment variables.

**Important:** The `pub` directory should be the public root of your application and should not be included in URL.

When you want to use 1st or 2nd option you will have the same shared `static` and `media` resources (the same path) for all stores under website.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to check the URL in the index.php inside pub.
Check the URL In the core_config_table.
If you are using the Nginx then you need to create separate hosts for that site.
Check the pub Media folder.
```

I think this resolves your issue.